# Cancel ComboBox dropdown closing

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to cancel this operation if the user selects a specific item because I don't want to force the user to open the dropdown again.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you putting that item into the drop down list if you will not allow the user to select it? Can you modify your design to provide a more useful user interface?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just use [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) control? Preventing combobox closing is imho a bad UI design idea...

Answer (score 0):

You're going to override expected behavior of common control and it's not a good idea. If you want to provide some kind of hierarchical selection use ListBox or TreeView.